# Soldering a new pin onto a DIP switch

Tags: soldering

I am currently working on a small electrical task involving a DIP switch. I actually removed this DIP switch from another piece of circuitry, but one of the pins broke off in the process.

I attempted to add another pin back to it, but as I tried, the plastic case melted a bit (not too big of an issue) and the solder didn't stick. The real problem is the solder not sticking. Is there a way to make this process easier, or just work in general?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a new switch and it would be more reliable. Don't trust artistic soldering.

Comment: use a dual pin header and jumpers ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pin+header+jumpers&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: To get a better answer to your question as stated, _edit you question_ with pictures of what you have.  However, in almost all cases, the better answer to your _larger_ question is to just replace the DIP switch.

Comment: This is all too vague, you don't even mention if it is SMT or through-hole.

Answer (score 2):

It might be hard to reattach the pin. Depends on a dip switch are attached either via solder, wire or crimp. If it's the solder or wire type one would need to re-solder or rewire the PIN internal to the dip switch. I guess you could use a meter to determine conductivity by pushing the pin in and see if you get conductivity when the switch is on but the easiest thing to do would be to simply get a new dip switch they're cheap but you might have to wait a little bit

Another though you might want to try is use a 0.1“ header and a jumper as an alternative